# Preciso declarar a Versão do SVG na tag?

Tags: html5, navegador-de-internet, svg, w3c

Estou com uma dúvida sobre a necessidade de declarar a versão do SVG na tag `<svg>`

Sei que o SVG começou com a versão `1.0`, `1.1`, `1.2` e agora está na versão `2.0`. Alguns SVG vejo com a declaração da versão e outros sem, porém os dois são renderizados normalmente pelo Browser. Também sei que existem várias mudanças entre a versão `1.2` e `2.0`.

Ai ficou a dúvida, uma vez que eu não declaro a versão do SVG como o navegador vai saber qual versão estou usado?
 ***Existe realmente a necessidade de declarar o `version` já que têm coisas bem diferentes entre uma versão e outra?***

Exemplo com `version="1.1"` declarada.

```html
<svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="612px" height="502.174px" viewBox="0 65.326 612 502.174" >
    <ellipse class="ground" cx="183.5" cy="187.5" rx="159" ry="80"/>
</svg>
```

**Exemplo sem `version` declarada**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 10">
  <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe.

Conforme [documentação na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/version), o atributo `version` é puramente informativo, sem nenhuma influência em como os elementos serão processados ou renderizados.

Tanto que a partir da versão 2.0 o [atributo está obsoleto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg#Attributes).